# Appending and deleting row from a response sheet from older timestamp?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am having a google response sheet. I run this sheet every night at 12. whenever some response are received I want to append the row to another sheet and delete the respective row in form responses. Here I want to start appending from the oldest timestamp in form responses i.e. from row number two as row number 1 is questions. whenever  Irun this code, I am successfully appending the row but not able to delete the row.
Here is the code I am trying to do:

```
//** Copying the response to another Spreadsheet for roster management**//
 function copySheet(){
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = source.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
  var lastRow = sourceSheet.getLastRow();
  var getData = sourceSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var destSheet = source.getSheetByName("10017135ADC");
  Logger.log(lastRow);
   if(lastRow >1){
    for (var j =1; j<lastRow; j++) {
    //    Logger.log(j);
       var rowData = getData[j];
    //    Logger.log(rowData);
       destSheet.appendRow(rowData);
       sourceSheet.deleteRow(j);
    } 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 function copySheet(){
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = source.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
  var lastRow = sourceSheet.getLastRow();
  var getData = sourceSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var destSheet = source.getSheetByName("10017135ADC");
  Logger.log(lastRow);
  let d=0;//keep track of deleted rows 
   if(lastRow >1){
    for (var j =1; j<lastRow; j++) {
    //    Logger.log(j);
       var rowData = getData[j];
    //    Logger.log(rowData);
       destSheet.appendRow(rowData);
       sourceSheet.deleteRow(j-d++);
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but on execution the error is Exception: Cannot delete row with form questions. Consider hiding the row instead.

Comment: "row with form questions" is the top row of the sheet(The questions of your form). That's the only row that cannot be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Cooper's new variable approach was good. But **upwards for deletion** is a better approach.

Try something like this

```
for (var i = getData.length - 1; i > 1; i--) {
  //anything you want to perform
  destSheet.appendRow(getData[i]);
  sheet.deleteRow(i);
}
```